# Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read when passing a callback function

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to pass a callback function to a constructor:

```
//menu.dart

class _MenuState extends State<Menu> {  

    void callbackFunc() {
        // does something...
    }

    List<Widget> pages = [Home(callback: callbackFunc), Search(), Profile()];

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

       ...

    }
}


//home.dart

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
    final Function callback;
    Home({ Key? key, required this.callback }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}
```

But I get this error:

> Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'callbackFunc'.

Is there a way to pass the callbackFunc to the Home constructor argument ?

Comment: make you callbackFunc a static function or move it outside of your _MenuState class

Comment: `late List<Widget> pages`